# Latin usage & perfect passive finite verb forms

Tags: syntax, word-order, word-usage, perfect-tense, esse

I understand that a perfect passive finite verb is formed by combining the perfect passive participle with the correct form of 'esse'. My question is this:

Does it ever happen that the second component of a perfect passive finite verb (the form of 'esse') either precedes or is separated by a few words from the other component (the perfect passive participle)?

I am wondering because I have had trouble, in practice, distinguishing a perfect passive verb from a mere predication using a perfect passive participle (in cases where the third person 'est' is used, as it would be in the verb form). Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for an interesting question! I hope that you will register your account and stick around; the site is much more flexible for a registered user. If you want a quick introduction to how the site works, you can check [our introductory tour](https://latin.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it does happen.
The *esse* and the perfect participle need not be anywhere near each other.
For example, Cicero (in Verrem 2.1.16) writes:

> In Siciliam **sum** inquirendi causa **profectus**.

The verb *proficisci* is deponent, but it doesn't invalidate the point.
The same freedom is found with other verbs as well (Pro Caecina 84.1):

> …**sum** ex eo loco **deiectus**…

Latin word order is flexible also in the sense that words that belong together can be quite far from each other.
The examples are from Cicero to show that this is not bad or marginal style.